# Получаю неправильную информацию из COM port-а

Tags: c++, arduino, com-port

Новичок, но по воле судьбы решил поработать с COM портом на языке C++. Передаю информацию в COM с помощью **Arduino nano (Китай, old loader (Вдруг это как-то повлияет)), код представлен ниже.**

```
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
Serial.print(95);
}
```

Ардуинка подключена в COM6. **Код программы, с принимающей стороны.**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // для system
using namespace std;
//. . .

int main()
{
    HANDLE Port;
    const int READ_TIME = 20;
    OVERLAPPED sync = { 0 };
    int reuslt = 0;
    unsigned long wait = 0, read = 0, state = 0;
    unsigned char  dst[2] = {0};
    unsigned long size = sizeof(dst);
    sync.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    //. . .
    Port = CreateFile(L"COM6", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
    if (Port == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Невозможно открыть последовательный порт", L"Error", MB_OK);
        ExitProcess(1);
    }
    
    while (true) {
        /* Устанавливаем маску на события порта */
        if (SetCommMask(Port, EV_RXCHAR)) {
            /* Связываем порт и объект синхронизации*/
            WaitCommEvent(Port, &state, &sync);
            /* Начинаем ожидание данных*/
            wait = WaitForSingleObject(sync.hEvent, READ_TIME);
            /* Данные получены */
            if (wait == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
                /* Начинаем чтение данных */
                ReadFile(Port, dst, size, &read, &sync);
                /* Ждем завершения операции чтения */
                wait = WaitForSingleObject(sync.hEvent, READ_TIME);
                /* Если все успешно завершено, узнаем какой объем данных прочитан */
                if (wait == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                    if (GetOverlappedResult(Port, &sync, &read, FALSE))
                        reuslt = read;

                cout << dst << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

**А теперь самое интересное - иногда данные проскакиваю верные**, но они каким-либо образом инвертированы/искажены. Т.е если шлю в порт с Ардуино 123, на выходе получаю 312. Если 95 - 59. Но чаще всего (99% случаев) - информация просто на просто искажается и вместо 95 на выходе получаю следующее [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ну или набор беспорядочных цифр по типу**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: COM-порт на хосте нужно корректно настроить. Что используется бодрейт 9600 бод, что данные передаются в формате 8N1 и прочие параметры. А вы просто открываете COM-порт и пытаетесь что-то из него читать.

Comment: Поправил, но ничего не изменилось , **добавил** следующее `DCB dcb;` **в самом начале** перед `main()` и 
`GetCommState(Port, &dcb);
dcb.ByteSize = 2; //Биты данных - 2
dcb.Parity = 0;  // Четность - N
dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
SetCommState(Port, &dcb);` 
**Прямо после создания порта, перед `if (Port == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)`**. Приходит опять же крокозябра

Comment: Конечно кракозябры, если ByteSize должен быть 8.
https://coderoad.ru/8190782/Arduino-%D0%B8-Windows-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переписал программу. Считаю, что дело было в эвентах и данные как-то искажались, хотя не могу сказать ввиду своей безграмотности и незнания. Новый код работает корректно.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

HANDLE hSerial;

void ReadCOM()
{
    DWORD iSize;
    char sReceivedChar;
    while (true)
    {
        ReadFile(hSerial, &sReceivedChar, 1, &iSize, 0);  // получаем 1 байт
        if (iSize > 0)   // если что-то принято, выводим
            cout << sReceivedChar;
    }
}

int main()
{
    LPCTSTR sPortName = L"COM6";
    hSerial = ::CreateFile(sPortName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            cout << "serial port does not exist.\n";
        }
        cout << "some other error occurred.\n";
    }
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    if (!GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
    {
        cout << "getting state error\n";
    }
    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;
    if (!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
    {
        cout << "error setting serial port state\n";
    }
    while (1)
    {
        ReadCOM();
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как уже сказал @Vanyamba Electronics, вам нужно настроить порт. Если мне не изменяет память, используя WinAPI, сделать это можно так:

```
DCB dcb;
hPort=CreateFile("COM1", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
GetCommState(hPort, &dcb);
dcb.ByteSize = 8; //Биты данных - 8
dcb.Parity = 0;  // Четность - N
dcb.StopBits = 0; //Стоп-бит  -1
//...Остальные настройки, если нужны
SetCommState(hPort, &dcb);
```

P.S. Писал по памяти, но должно работать.

Comment: Поправил, но ничего не изменилось , добавил следующее `DCB dcb;` в самом начале перед `main()` и 
`GetCommState(Port, &dcb);
dcb.ByteSize = 2; //Биты данных - 2
dcb.Parity = 0;  // Четность - N
dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
SetCommState(Port, &dcb);` 
Прямо после создания порта и перед if. Приходит опять же крокозябра

Comment: @ВладимирЯранцев  Вы указали формат байта `2N?` Знаком вопрос я обозначил кол-во стоповых бит, которые вы вообще не задали и не указали какие были считаны из настроек порта. Также, формат байта 2N, если кто-то и использует (что вряд-ли ) то мне об этом не известно. У ардуинки по умолчанию формат байта `8N1`, который и был задан в моем примере. Вы добавили настройку скорости - это правильно. Задайте нормальный формат байта и тогда будем разбираться дальше.

Comment: Так, сменил настройки на следующие
`dcb.ByteSize = 8; //Биты данных - 8
 dcb.Parity = 0;  // Четность - N
 dcb.StopBits = 0; //Стоп-бит  -1
 dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600; 
` 
- и прогресс имеется, теперь каждый раз выдаются правильные числа (которые я пишу), но в каком-то странном порядке, шлю 321, приходит следующее 132╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠

Comment: Только обрадовался - все по старой. Вбил число 91, в ком порте на ПК выдается - NLN╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠ или LNL╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠

Comment: @ВладимирЯранцев ,  по поводу порядка - все правильно, ардуино шлет пакеты младшим байтом вперед, отсюда и преобразование 321 ->132, эту ситуацию нужно обрабатывать уже после приема пакета. По поводу крякозябров - у вас приемный буфер 2 байта, а принимаете вы каким-то образом 3. нужно смотреть в отладчике что на самом деле там происходит при приеме, и что важнее при отправке. Можете попробовать поставить просулшку порта и посмотреть какие данные через него проходят (DeviceMonitorStudio - неплохая штука).

Comment: сделал следующее сделал буфер на 256 символов 
`unsigned char  dst[256] ;
unsigned long size = 256;`

Все остальное оставил также - сначала числа приходят (если пишут допустим 3-х значные, но как только пишу 2-х значые - все , получается как-то так и дальше - что не пишу - все приходит в таком же формате **К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬К┬╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠**

Comment: К сожалению я не могу воспроизвести у себя такую проблему. По хорошему нужно видеть, что происходит с обеих сторон: как отправки так и получения. По идее, на стороне приемника, с учетом всего вышесказанного, все должно работать правильно. Для разнообразия, попробуйте настроить порт на работу в синхронном режиме (снимите флаг OVERLAPPED), дальше нужно будет думать в зависимости от того что получите.